# How to create an FSM with the following conditions?

Tags: diagram, finite-automata, state-machine, states

I'm trying to explain the following conditions and thought that an FSM might be the best way but now I'm having troubles to develop it.

So here's the conditions:

```
S_0 if True self-loops 

S_0 if False goes to S_1

S_1 if True goes back to S_0

S_1 if False goes back to S_0

S_1 goes to S_2 if both S_0 and S_1 are False

S_2 will go back to S_0 if both false and true
```

Here is the FSM that I developed

[image]

but then I realized that it's not quite right and I can't think of how to satisfy these conditions. Can a FSM diagram have more than 1 instance of the same state? i.e can i have 2 S_0's on the diagram?

Comment: What do you mean by "if both S0 and S1 are false"? A state does not have a value.

Comment: ok let me reword that to a finite state machine that accepts the alphabets {T,F} and these are the state transitions.

Comment: I get that, but one of your rules isn't what a FSM rule looks like. How do you phrase your second-to-last rule as "In state S1, if input is T then go to state XX, if input is F then goto state YY"? You seem to be referring to a memory of what happened in state S0 at an earlier point.

Comment: My FSM diagram is wrong which is why i came for help. This isn't an FSM that has an accept state. If the input is F,F,F,F  then the current state should be S2  If the input is T, state should be s0. if the input is F, current state should be S1. if the input is FT, the current state should be s0. if F,F,F,F without it ruining the whole picture.

Comment: to add to the last line. S0 F S1.....S1 F S0....S0 F S1...S1 F S2.

Comment: Yet again: what do you intend the rule "S_1 goes to S_2 **if both S_0 and S_1 are False**" to mean?

Comment: you can ignore that and just look at this one instead:  S0 input F, goes to S1. S1 inputs F goes back to S0. S0 input F goes to S1. S1 input F now goes to S2.

Comment: Ok, got it. Yes, it looks like you'll need another state that behaves mostly like S0, other than that you go back to that "copy" from S1 on F. (Remember that the Sx are just names. So, you can't have another S0, but it doesn't matter.)

Comment: So you want your state machine to reach `S2` when 2 occurances of `false` is processed? Then, once at `S2`, transition back to `S1` to start it over? Just want to make sure I understand. When should this machine end? It seems `S2` would be the accept state (after finding 2 occurances of `false`), but you request that it goes back to `S0`